# More advanced :assoc with elixir absinthe

Tags: elixir, graphql, ecto, absinthe

My blog app has a `Post` model that has many `Comment`s.

```
schema "post" do
  field :title, :string
  field :content, :string

  belongs_to :owner, MyApp.Accounts.User, foreign_key: :owner_id

  has_many :comments, MyApp.Content.Comment, foreign_key: :post_id

  timestamps()
end
```

I have an associated absinthe object as well.

```
object :post do
  field :id, :integer
  field :title, :string
  field :content, :string
  field :owner, :user, resolve: assoc(:owner)
  field :comments, list_of(:comment), resolve: assoc(:comments)
end
```

Queries work as expected.

Now I want to add a boolean `active` field to the `Comments` schema so that I can perform soft deletes; I'll only select comments where `active == true`, and I will delete comments by setting `active` to `false`.

I add the field into my schema:

```
field :active, :boolean, default: true, null: false
```

Now I only want the absinthe `:comments` field to return active comments.  I have a custom resolver for this...

```
field :comments, list_of(:comment), resolve: fn (query,_,resolution) ->
  query =
    from c in MyApp.Content.Comment,
      where: c.post_id == ^query.id,
      where: c.active == true,
      select: c

  {:ok, MyApp.Repo.all(query)}
end
```

I'm worried this is going to run into an N+1 problem though.  Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `Batch Resolver` here. The [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/absinthe/Absinthe.Middleware.Batch.html#module-example-usage) explains everything in detail. Your query should look like the following:

```
query =
  from c in MyApp.Content.Comment,
    where: c.post_id in ^post_ids,
    where: c.active == true,
    select: c

{:ok, query |> MyApp.Repo.all() |> Enum.group_by(& &1.post_id)}
```